# Why is idempotence sufficient to be a projection?

Tags: geometry, category-theory

Wikipedia's definition of projection is that idempotence is sufficient. Why does this make sense?

The physical idea of projection is to a lower-dimensional space. So is the projection operator of statistics. Software tasks like saving, rsync-ing, pushing to live, or running an anti-virus check are idempotent, but don't seem like projections.

Comment: Wikipedia defines a projection in *linear algebra* as *"a linear transformation P from a vector space to itself such that $P^2 = P$. "*. I do not see how that applies to running an anti-virus check.

Comment: @MartinR thinking more of the categorical definition

Comment: @MartinR but maybe the answer is the same: it isn't the idempotence that's sufficient, it's idempotence and endo-.

Comment: Generally, one could conceive of most of the above examples as pairs $(C,S)$ where $C$ is current/active/live state of something and $S$ is the stored state. Then the above processes all theoretically map $(C,S) \to (C,C)$ which is a projection onto the diagonal. Of course this is a bit dishonest, but it seems not bad.

Comment: @MartinR incidentally I only glanced at the Wikipedia definition. I was at a lee homology talk where $p \circ p=p$ was the definition of projection and was thinking back to that.

Comment: @JHance I like that! Why is it dishonest? I think you are modeling the core issue nicely. If not pairs then there needs to be some extra structure to smooth out what I said.

Comment: Similarly a pure detection virus check will map $(K, D, U ) \to (D, D ,U)$ where $K$ denotes known viruses, $D$ denotes detectable but not necessarily known, and $U$ denotes undetected and undetectable (by the given software)

Comment: So, this is just a question about what the word "projection" means? Seems like pedantry about definitions more than anything substantive to me.

Comment: @KevinCarlson It's not really about "the" definition, but about why.